# Validation error of type SubSelectionRequired: Sub selection required for type Timestamp of field

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-spqr

I use GraphQL-SPQR Library
The problem is "Validation error of type SubSelectionRequired: Sub selection required for type Timestamp"
Maybe there is expression in query for timestamp 
or format in Entity

```
{"query":
"{findUserPointByUserId(userId:73){rowNum userAccountPointUserId totalPoint pointTypeDescription point userAccountCreatedDate} findUserAccountImgByUserId(userId:73){imageId,userId,presentImgNum}}"


}
```

Error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Validation error of type SubSelectionRequired: Sub selection required for type Timestamp of field userAccountCreatedDate",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 103
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Entity

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_user_account_point", schema = "public", catalog = "corus")
public class ViewUserAccountPoint {
    @Id
    @Basic
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "rowNum")
    @Column(name = "row_num", nullable = true)
    private Long rowNum;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_account_point_userid", nullable = true)
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "userAccountPointUserId")
    private Integer userAccountPointUserId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "subject_id", nullable = true)
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "subjectId")
    private Integer subjectId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "point", nullable = true)
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "point")
    private Integer point;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_account_point_typeid", nullable = true)
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "userAccountPointTypeId")
    private Integer userAccountPointTypeId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = true)
    @GraphQLQuery(name = "userAccountCreatedDate")
    private Timestamp userAccountCreatedDate;
```

Service

```
public List<ViewUserAccountPoint> findUserPointByUserId(@GraphQLArgument(name = "userId") Integer userId){
        return viewUserAccountPointRepository.findByUserAccountPointUserIdOrderByUserAccountCreatedDateDesc(userId);
    }
```

Controller

```
 private final GraphQL graphQL;

    public UserController(UserAccountService userAccountService) {
        GraphQLSchema schema = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator()
                .withResolverBuilders(
                        //Resolve by annotations
                        new AnnotatedResolverBuilder())
                .withOperationsFromSingleton(userAccountService,UserAccountService.class)
                .withValueMapperFactory(new JacksonValueMapperFactory())
                .generate();
        graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/graphql", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> graphql(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request, HttpServletRequest raw) {
        ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(request.get("query"))
                .operationName(request.get("operationName"))
                .context(raw)
                .build());
        return executionResult.toSpecification();
    }
```

I search through all query timestamp format 
However, i couldn't find 
i hope to hear the solution.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

For one reason or another, `Timestamp` got mapped incorrectly. It ended up being an object and not a scalar.
As mentioned in [the issue you opened](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/251), it's unclear where is `Timestamp` in your code coming from.

`java.sql.Timestamp` is [supported out of the box](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/master/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/util/Scalars.java#L266) in recent versions of GraphQL SPQR, so you might be on an older version.

If that's not the case, it would mean `Timestamp` is some other than `java.sql.Timestamp`, and you'd need to register a custom mapper for it.

```
public class TimestampMapper implements TypeMapper {

    // Define the scalar as needed, see io.leangen.graphql.util.Scalars for inspiration
    private static final GraphQLScalarType TIMESTAMP = ...;

    @Override
    public GraphQLOutputType toGraphQLType(AnnotatedType javaType, OperationMapper operationMapper, Set<Class<? extends TypeMapper>> mappersToSkip, BuildContext buildContext) {
        return TIMESTAMP; //it's important to always return the same instance
    }

    @Override
    public GraphQLInputType toGraphQLInputType(AnnotatedType javaType, OperationMapper operationMapper, Set<Class<? extends TypeMapper>> mappersToSkip, BuildContext buildContext) {
        return TIMESTAMP; //same as above
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(AnnotatedType type) {
        return ClassUtils.isSuperClass(Timestamp.class, type);
    }
}
```

Then register your mapper:

```
generator.withTypeMappers(new TimestampMapper())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect query body for my case, make sure you have the right one.